# Flexbox image scale to height and keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a DIV which is scaled to available height using CSS flexbox. In this DIV is an image which I would like to scale along with the DIV in both dimensions. That means it should be scaled keeping its aspect ratio and the dimensions which is less than the respective DIV dimension should be centered.

I can make the image follow the width of the DIV, but not the height. Therefore, portrait images escape from the DIV bounds.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aer69rcr/) to demonstrate the problem.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background: pink;">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/300" />
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to make the image fit the height even if it's naturally smaller? (You are using a rather large picture in your example, so I'm not sure)

Comment: First thing I'd like to achieve is that it scales down as required.

Comment: Nope, sorry, the image shall retain its original aspect ration. If this one differs from the one of the container, the image should be centered along the axis that is smaller than the one of the container after resizing.

Comment: Thanks. Rephrased. Using a background image could be a last resort, since the images are the main content of the site and that should usually be represented via HTML and not as the style. But if nothing else works out...

Comment: Was the flexbox layout implemented because of the image scaling problem this pertains to, or for other reasons? (I.e.: would it be an option to change to block DIVs?)

Comment: I might be able to change to something different, but using flexboxes was actually quite easy to accomplish what I needed so far.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one `box` per container? Do you ever want the container to grow taller than the viewport? A mockup of what you're going for would be very helpful here, especially since the image link in your fiddle is broken.

Comment: this should show problem better, http://jsfiddle.net/5ohw433s/9/ there are possible hacks like recalculate image aspect in transaction etc, but all of them works not so good.

Answer (score 15):

When you specify the height as a percentage value, that is a percentage with respect to the height of the parent element. It is also true with the `<img>` tag.

In this unknown height flexbox layout, you can use the `position` tricks to make the image to fit both the width and height of the flex item, and use `transform` tricks to do the centering.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vv4g7f5f/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
}
.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/300" />
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use `background` image, that can make it much easier, the key is to use the value `contain`. See the simplified demo below.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/denjp4zt/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink url(//dummyimage.com/300) no-repeat center center / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

**if you can change from flex to block**:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/ug6eoxfs/

as @janfoeh pointed out, using object-fit: contain makes it possible:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.box {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 5%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.box img {
    height:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    display:block;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

If the Flex Layout is needed, as a last resort you might consider using a background-image, which makes the whole thing really easy: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/e1c2tLme/

```
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
```

Other than that, I can't find a way that doesn't involve scripting.

Comment: Sorry, but that is exactly what I have in the fiddle and it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will give that a try and see whether I can rearrange my layout or switch to background images. I am not sure whether I can accept this is an answer to the specific flexbox question though.

Comment: yes, it's not ideal.
So JavaScript is not an option?

Comment: I usually block javascript in my browser. So would be a bad habit to use it for my own site ;)

Comment: @languitar block javascript? damn, daniel

Answer (score 6):

**Uses flexbox!** ([JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/darrylyeo/betae931/))

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

The key is to use `object-fit: contain;` to maintain the aspect ratio, and `align-items: stretch;` to ensure the image is not cut off on the left and right (might this be a bug?).

Comment: This does indeed constrain the image, but it leaves extra height. See https://fiddle.jshell.net/betae931/1 at narrow panel widths.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @darrylyeo answer.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
}

.box {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete the image tag and set it as the background of the `.box` div with `background-size:cover;`
[**jsfiddle 1**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5j7sLb7L/)

or, if you want to avoid cropping:

Delete the image tag and set it as the background of the `.box` div with `background-size:contain;`
[**jsfiddle 2**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9x040L10/)

Comment: Both cases result in image cropping.

Comment: You haven't shown a flex container matching the height of the image. This doesn't meet the requirements of the OP.